# Deployment Error with Sencha SDK Tool

Tags: model-view-controller, deployment, extjs4, extjs

I'm trying to deploy my extJS-Application, which is in MVC-Architecture style.
As described in the [extJS Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/getting_started) I've first tried to generate a JSB3 File with `sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3`.
Sadly I've got the following error: `undefined:0 TypeError: 'null' is not a constructor`

I'm working on MAC OS X with Sencha Command v1.2.2.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: same question (with solution) in the [sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?140600-Deployment-Error-with-Sensha-SDK-Tool-null-is-not-a-constructor).

Answer (score 0):

got the same error.  On windows 7. Ext 4.0.2.  Not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you include ext-dev.js in your app and you don't have any warnings/errors in Firebug/WebInspector.

Also check this thread: [[SDKTOOLS-3] buggy Sencha SDK Tools](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136032-SDKTOOLS-3-buggy-Sencha-SDK-Tools&p=636439&viewfull=1#post636439)

Answer (score 0):

Two days ago I was suffering such type of problem. Due to my absent mind I forgot to requires some of Ext or Ext.ux class. So think some of your Extjs Class may be missing. just requires it as I pointed or add these library to your Controller/Viewport/View/Store.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : enabled
});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Your.ns', 'app');
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'ux');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.ModelMgr.*',
    'Ext.panel.Panel',
    'Ext.button.Button',
    'Ext.window.Window',  
    'Ext.toolbar.TextItem',
    'Ext.menu.Menu',
    'Ext.toolbar.Spacer',
    'Ext.button.Split',
    'Ext.form.field.TextArea',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging', 
    'Ext.ModelManager',
    'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager',
    'Ext.tree.Column',
    'Ext.tree.Panel',
    'Ext.tree.View',
    'Ext.Loader',
    //..........................................
    // --Your Missing require library add here--
    //................................... ......
    'Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor',
    'Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy',
    'Ext.ux.PreviewPlugin',
    'Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager',
    'Ext.ux.statusbar.StatusBar',
]);

Ext.application({
    name        : 'Your.ns', 
    appFolder   : 'app',
    controllers : ['Your controllers'],
    models      : ['Your models'],
    stores      : ['Your stores'],
    views       : ['Your views'],
    launch      : function() {
        //TODO
    },
    autoCreateViewport: true
});
```

or add your missing class in requires array

```
Ext.define('Your.ns.controller.YourController', {
    extend      : 'Ext.app.Controller', 
    requires    : ['your required class1 here', 'your required class2 here'],
    views       : [],

    refs        : [{
           ref      : '',
           selector : 'window'
    }],

    init       : function() {        
           this.control({ 
              // your action
           });
        },
        //your code here
});
```

I think this code may be helpful.